# How to change view height according to it is recently added subview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I have such problem, while trying to create a simple messenger.
Here what I came to:

1. `class ChatBubleUIView` that class is responsible for creating a bubleview with label in it. It works fine, calculating view height according to label height
2. Inside my cell I've created a content view. In the cell class, I'm adding new `ChatBubleUIView` instance as a subview to content View.
3. The problem is that, content doesn't scale up to the size of my `ChatBubleInstance`.

   ```
   class ChatMessageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, MessageCellConfiguration {

   var message: Message?

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
   }

   func configureCell() {

           let chatBubleView = ChatBubleUIView(message: message!)
           self.addSubview(chatBubleView)
   } 
   }
   ```
4. In my tableView delegate

   ```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell") as! ChatMessageTableViewCell
    let data = currentUser.mesaageHistory[indexPath.row]

   cell.message = data
   cell.configureCell()

   return cell
   }
   ```
5. Also I have set estimated row height for my tableView

   ```
    messageTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    messageTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
   ```

What should I do to set to my tableView row height chatViewBubleUIView instance height.
Previously, I solved this problem using old-school approach, programmaticly determine chatViewBubleUIView instance height and then implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. But I'd like to do that using AutoLayoaut.

Answer (score 1):

set your label's four constraint like `top,bottom,leading,trailing` and number of height of your label should be `0`.  Then it will automatically increased it's height as per content. If you are taking this label in any view then view's constrains should be same as label i have mentioned above!

Comment: Should I do that in the cell class?

Comment: You can do it in your storyboard or xib! And yes you can do in cell also!